# FileNotFoundException with absolute path

Tags: path

I have a directory like this:

```
assigment
 |
 |__ src
 |   |
 |   |__ Main.scala
 |
 |
 |__ testcase
     |
     |__ Simple.in
```

In **Main.scala**, **Simple.in** is read by `Source.fromFile()`:

```
val inputFile = "Simple.in"
val lines = Source.fromFile("./testcase/" + inputFile).getLines
```

But when I run **Main.scala** in `sbt` the `FileNoutFoundException` appear. When I change the path to `"../testcase/" + inputFile` then it works fine. The original path is from my teacher, so I wonder which path is actually correct? Oh, I'm using Linux btw...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

./ means: the current path

../ means: the directory "above" the current directory

Thus: when you **run** your Scala class from "src", "./testcase" makes it look for a directory testcase within "src"; or using full path names:

"assignment/src/" + "./testcase" turns into "assignment/src/testcase"

Whereas, when you use

"assignment/src/" + "../testcase" turns into "assignment/testcase"

therefore, the version with ".." finds the valid path. That is all the magic here!

Answer (score 1):

`.` => current dir

`..` => one above curren dir

But standard way to access resources is using the `resources` folder of sbt project structure.

This way helps you to access files independent of where (which class) you are accessing the resource in the code.

Folder to put your files

```
src/main/resources

val stream : InputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/readme.txt")
val lines = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream( stream ).getLines
```